# как распознать кириллицу из библиотеки firebase_ml_vision?

Tags: flutter

данная библиотека `firebase_ml_vision` хорошо работает с латиницей, а вот мне необходимо распознавание кириллицы, может кто-то подскажет как это реализовать, чтобы пользователь мог сфотографировать текст из книжки и выводить текст на экран?

Comment: а чем она лучше [tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract)?

Comment: а эта библиотека умеет переводить комбинированные символы?

Comment: комбинированные с чем?

Comment: кириллица + латиница

Comment: тут есть web-версия, попробуйте её https://tesseract.projectnaptha.com/

Comment: там дропнуть на страницу любую картинку с текстом и нажать для начала распознавания

Comment: Да, там можно указать несколько языков для распознавания, а также заранее отметить области текста или таблиц